# Spark read files of different column types

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have partitioned  directory in s3 one below format:

```
database/year=2022/mth=1/id=1/file1.parquet
database/year=2022/mth=12/id=2/file2.parquet
database/year=2022/mth=3/id=3/file3.parquet
database/year=2022/mth=8/id=4/file4.parquet
```

The issue I have is that these files contain a column impression in different data types eg file1 contains a column impression in double and file2 in decimal. There are few other columns that have different types too.
Below is the spark query I tried. it errors  saying `Column: [impressions], Expected: bigint, Found: DOUBLE`

```scala
sparkSession.read()
        .option("header", true)
        .option("basePath", basePath)
        .schema(schema)
        .parquet(basePath + input)
        .filter(col("year").equalTo(key).and(col("mth").isin(value.toArray()))
                .and(col("id").isin(idList.toArray())));
```

I have tried using `mergeSchema` and providing a schema during read as well. No luck so far. Has anyone had the same issue?

Comment: If you are receiving both bigint and decimal values, define the column as decimal (whatever precision and scale you need).  Spark will implicitly cast the bigints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spark, I don't think there is a simple way to reconcile numeric types. So first we need to decide what we want. Let's decide to cast everything as doubles. In that case, we can read every file separately, cast every numeric values to doubles and then merge everything like this:

```scala
// a function to read a file and cast its numeric columns to doubles.
def read_with_doubles(path : String) = {
    val df = spark.read.parquet(path)
    val columns = df.schema.fields
        .map(f => if(f.dataType.isInstanceOf[NumericType])
                       col(f.name) cast "double" as f.name
                  else
                       col(f.name)
        )
    df.select(columns : _*)
}

// a functions to extract partition columns from the file paths,
// and add the corresponding columns to the dataframes
def extract_partitions(path : String) = {
     path.split("/")
         .filter(_ contains '=')
         .map(_.split("="))
         .map(x => x(0) -> x(1))
         .map{ case(name, value) => lit(value) as name }
}

// just using binaryFiles to list all file paths without using other libs
// feel free to use s3 clients instead.
val files = sc.binaryFiles(basePath + input + "/*/*/*").map(_._1).collect

val result = files
    .map(file => file -> read_with_doubles(file))
    .map{ case (file, df) => df.select(df.columns.map(col) ++ extract_partitions(file) : _*) }
    .reduce(_ union _)
```